# how to remove a character with jquery

Tags: jquery, regex, replace

I have this:

```
<span class="name"><span class="gost">Yahoo</span>, </span>
```

I tried something like this, but no luck:

```
$("span.name").html(
    $(this).replace(/,/g, '')
);
```

Comment: Yes, because replace returns the latest changed result, it doesn't do anything on the instance. String.Replace, because strings are immutable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
v = $("span.name").html().replace(/,/g,'');
$("span.name").html(v);
```

Try that

Comment: Thank you Well said , would you please describe about your regular expression ?